# Does Symfony 2 controller beforeAction exist?

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a method like `beforeAction` for Symfony 2 controllers? Also, is there a generic `beforeAction` for the entire bundle/project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't a `preExecute` equivalent in symfony2, but instead you have access to a more powerful events model.

[This article](http://symfony2.ylly.fr/symfony2-simulate-preexecute-postexecute-filters-actions-jordscream/) explains how to add a listener.

The event you want to listen to is `onCoreController`

Also see: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#the-event-dispatcher